# Get $M$ and all the roots of ecutions to be real

Tags: polynomials

Get $M$ and all the roots of ecutions to be real
$x^4 - (2m-1)x^2 +4m -5 =0$

If I set $x^2=t$ I get some delta but idk how to solve that

Comment: Is "ecution" actually "equation"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variable $t=x^2$, so:
$$ t^2 - (2m-1) t + (4m -5) = 0 $$
Solve using [Quadratic Formula (check the link)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticFormula.html), and you can find that:
$$ (2m-1)^2 - 4(4m -5) \geq 0 $$
For real roots.

Answer (score 0):

calculate the term $$\left(\frac{2m-1}{2}\right)^2-(4m-5)$$

Comment: 4m^2+10m+21 .This also get delta <0

Comment: you must do case work